# c# .net display image

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to display 2 images as the result, but only 1 image displayed as a result. What is wrong with my code? Or is there anything I should know to do the job properly or am I missed something? Thanks.

PS. I'm very new at c# almost my first programming. So very detailed explanation will be very helpful and appreciated. Also please write the answer code to solve this problem. Thanks

This is my code.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            byte[] bitmapArray = new byte[2046 * 2046 * 3];



            for (int i = 0; i < 12558348; i++)
            {
                bitmapArray[i] = 127;
             }

            PixelFormat pf = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
            BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(2046, 2046, 96, 96, pf, null, bitmapArray, 2046 * 3);
            BaslerImage.Source = bitmap;

            Nothing(bitmapArray, pf);

        }

        async void Nothing(byte[] bitmapArray, PixelFormat pf)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 12558348; i++)
            {

                bitmapArray[i] = 30;

            }

            PixelFormat pf2 = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
            BitmapSource bitmap2 = BitmapSource.Create(2046, 2046, 96, 96, pf, null, bitmapArray, 2046 * 3);
            BaslerImage.Source = bitmap2;

            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do?  You state your problem, but not really the task.  Why are you creating an array of bytes and then using that to create a bitmap?

Comment: In both methods you assign the resulting image to `BaslerImage.Source`...so you overwrite the first image with the second one in the same place. You probably need two separate places for displaying the images.

Comment: I was trying to make very simple bitmap images. And could you please explain me little more about how to display the images separately? I was also guessing that the results might overwrited, but doesn't know how to fix it.

Comment: And sorry that my codes may not look so nice because I'm very new to programming.

Comment: `about how to display the images separately` Are they next to each other? Above / below each other? Something else?

Comment: well what kind of object is `BaslerImage`? I assume it's some kind of thing which displays images on your form. It seems it can only have one data source, not two. So you need to make another one e.g. `BaslerImage2` and assign your second bitmap to that, instead of over-writing the first image.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks for your supports guys. My explanation about the job I want to do was not accurate. Sorry for that. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

I believe your task is to display multiple images on series by updating Image.Source property. Please refer to the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Nothing();
        }

        async void Nothing()
        {
            byte[] bitmapArray = new byte[2046 * 2046 * 3];

            byte a = 30;
            int b = 80;
            var k = a * 2 + b;

            for(int j =0; j < 10; j++)
            { 
                for (int i = 0; i < 12558348; i++)
                {
                    bitmapArray[i] = (byte)(63 + j*10);
                }
                PixelFormat pf = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
                BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(2046, 2046, 96, 96, pf, null, bitmapArray, 2046 * 3);
                BaslerImage.Source = bitmap;
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```